# React native - another name for Provider

Tags: react-native, mobx-react

I have a project with the following structure:

- **Services**  - plain typescript
- **Components** - TSX files
- **Handlers** - also TSX files but they have a different kind of logic in them. For example, I have a `message.handler.tsx` to handle all of my service messages.

I want to add another type with the following criteria:

- A handler but with only TypeScript code in it.
- Receives services as parameters in the constructor.

Example: `deepLink.handler.ts`. 
I'm using Mobx and passing my services as props. https://github.com/PrioritySoftware/priority-master-react/blob/master/src/app.tsx#L30

What is the correct way to achieve all of that?

Comment: What is the lifecycle of your handler? So for what are you using this handler? What is my first thought is that you initialize the handlers and stores at the same spot.

Comment: That's correct. I use my handles throughout the whole application.